# pandas dataframe: loc vs query performance

Tags: python, performance, pandas, dataframe, indexing

I have 2 dataframes in python that I would like to query for data.

- DF1: 4M records x 3 columns. The `query` function seems more
  efficient than the `loc` function.
- DF2: 2K records x 6 columns. The `loc` function seems much more
  efficient than the `query` function.

Both queries return a single record. The simulation was done by running the same operation 10K times.

Running python 2.7 and pandas 0.16.0

Any recommendations to improve the query speed?

Comment: Can you add some sample data for testing? But this [graph](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#performance-of-query) explain `query` should be faster in large data.

Comment: I think `query` will always carry a bit of overhead because of the string evaluation

Comment: Show us the query expression, how complex and expensive is it? Are you asking for suggestions on how to refactor it for speed?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

For improve performance is possible use `numexpr`:

```
import numexpr

np.random.seed(125)
N = 40000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'A':np.random.randint(10, size=N)})

def ne(df):
    x = df.A.values
    return df[numexpr.evaluate('(x > 5)')]
print (ne(df))

In [138]: %timeit (ne(df))
1 loop, best of 3: 494 ms per loop

In [139]: %timeit df[df.A > 5]
1 loop, best of 3: 536 ms per loop

In [140]: %timeit df.query('A > 5')
1 loop, best of 3: 781 ms per loop

In [141]: %timeit df[df.eval('A > 5')]
1 loop, best of 3: 770 ms per loop
```

---

```
import numexpr
np.random.seed(125)

def ne(x):
    x = x.A.values
    return x[numexpr.evaluate('(x > 5)')]

def be(x):
    return x[x.A > 5]

def q(x):
    return x.query('A > 5')

def ev(x):
    return x[x.eval('A > 5')]


def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=n), columns=['A'])
    return df


perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[ne, be, q, ev],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 25)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,  
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

[image: graph]

Edit:

Graph with modified `ne` and improved `be`:

```
def ne(x):
    return x[numexpr.evaluate('(x > 5)')]

def bex(x):
    return x[x.A.values > 5]
```

[image]

Comment: Nice answer.  I think that the "q" function in the second part should be `return x.query('A > 5')`

Comment: Making that change results in the "q" and "ev" lines being nearly identical, which makes sense since query is just a wrapper for the eval function

Comment: The `ne` function in the second part(graph code) doesn't return the same thing as the other functions. Every other function returns a `Pandas DataFrame` while `ne` returns a `numpy.Array`.  

When rewritten to match the `ne` function you have on the first part, its much closer to performing like `be`

You can also squeeze out a bit more performance out of `be` by writing it like `return return x[x.A.values > 5]`

Comment: I re-ran the test with a corrected `ne` and modified `be` functions as per @VictorUriarte 's comment above and edited the answer to show the extended graph.

Answer (score 9):

I've added the .loc function and used the same code @jezrael used to test the performance in `python 3.9.5` and `pandas 1.2.5`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import numexpr
import perfplot
np.random.seed(125)

def ne(x):
    return x[numexpr.evaluate('(x > 5)')]

def bex(x):
    return x[x.A.values > 5]

def be(x):
    return x[x.A > 5]

def lc(x):
    return x.loc[x.A > 5]

def lcx(x):
    return x.loc[x.A.values > 5]

def q(x):
    return x.query('A > 5')

def ev(x):
    return x[x.eval('A > 5')]

def make_df(n):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=n), columns=['A'])
    return df


perfplot.show(
    setup=make_df,
    kernels=[ne, lc, lcx, be, bex, q, ev],
    n_range=[2**k for k in range(2, 25)],
    logx=True,
    logy=True,
    equality_check=False,  
    xlabel='len(df)')
```

The using the `.loc` function does not afect the result of the `be` funcion and until 10^6 lines, using te column `.values` seens to be fastest option. The `query` method was the slowest.

[image: top5]

here just the loc and be, to see the overlap.
[image: loc vs. be]