# Speed up Python .loc function search

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, search

I am pulling out a value from a table, searching for the value based on matches in other columns. Right now, because there are hundreds of thousands of grid cells to go through, each call of the function takes a few seconds, but it adds up to hours. Is there a faster way to do this?

```
data_1 = data.loc[(data['test1'] == test1) & (data['test2'] == X) & (data['Column'] == col1) & (data['Row']== row1)].Value
```

Sample `data`

```
Column  Row Value   test2   test1
2       3   5       X       0TO4
2       6   10      Y       100UP
2       10  5.64    Y       10TO14
5       2   9.4     Y       15TO19
9       2   6       X       20TO24
13      11  7.54    X       25TO29
25      2   6.222   X       30TO34
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: looks like selecting the values as a list/series where all columns meet some condition.

Comment: Yes. It's looking for the value in column `Value` while matching all the other columns

Comment: Take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49937318/6361531

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be worth a quick read-through on the [enhancing performance docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/enhancingperf.html) to see what best fits your needs.

One option is to drop down to numpy using `.values` and slicing. Without seeing your actual data or use case, I created the following synthetic data:

```
data=pd.DataFrame({'column':[np.random.randint(30) for i in range(100000)],
                'row':[np.random.randint(50) for i in range(100000)],
                'value':[np.random.randint(100)+np.random.rand() for i in range(100000)],
                 'test1':[np.random.choice(['X','Y']) for i in range(100000)],
                'test2':[np.random.choice(['d','e','f','g','h','i']) for i in range(100000)]})

data.head()

    column  row value       test1   test2
0   4       30  88.367151   X       e
1   7       10  92.482926   Y       d
2   1       17  11.151060   Y       i
3   27      10  78.707897   Y       g
4   19      35  95.204207   Y       h
```

Then using `%timeit` I got the following results using `.loc` indexing, boolean masking, and numpy slicing 
(Note, at this point I realized I missed one of the lookups so that may affect the total time count but ratios should hold true)

```
%timeit data_1 = data.loc[(data['test1'] == 'X') & (data['column'] >=12) & (data['row'] > 22)]['value']
13 ms ± 538 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit data_1 = data[(data['test1'] == 'X') & (data['column'] >=12) & (data['row'] > 22)]['value']
13.1 ms ± 233 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Now, this next part contains some overhead for converting the dataframe to a numpy array. If you're converting it once then doing multiple lookups against it, then this will be faster. But if not, you will likely end up taking longer for a single convert/slice

Without considering conversion time:

```
d1=data.values

%timeit d1[(d1[:,3]=='X')&(d1[:,0]>=12)&(d1[:,1]>22)][:,2]
8.37 ms ± 161 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Approximately 30% improvement

With conversion time:

```
%timeit d1=data.values;d1[(d1[:,3]=='X')&(d1[:,0]>=12)&(d1[:,1]>22)][:,2]
20.6 ms ± 624 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
```

Approximately 50% worse

Comment: I tried this, converting it once and then indexing, and it went from 42 seconds to 33 secs for a test sample of the array

Comment: Glad this helped. I would still check out the link I included or the answer commented by @scottboston to see if numba, numexpr/eval, or cython might not be an even bigger improvement, admittedly with more effort on the front end

Answer (score 1):

You can index by `test1`, `test2`, `Column` and `Row`, and then lookup by that index.

Indexing:

```
data.set_index(["test1", "test2", "Column", "Row"], inplace=True)
```

and then lookup by doing this:

```
data_1 = data.loc[(test1, X, col1, row1)].Value
```

Comment: Very curious about this answer. Any idea how much it would speed things up?

Comment: Just tried this and it actually ended up taking longer. On a test file looking at 9 rows (querying a `data` file that is much larger, but looking for 9 values), it took 1 min and 5 sec versus 42 sec