# Pandas query() performance for filtering

Tags: pandas

I have read https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html  that using query() for dataframe filtering is faster than just using conditions with '&' to filter the data. Of course, there are some restrictions when query() can be used. BUt I tried it on a dataframe and actually performed significantly slower. Why is that so? What am I missing? When should query() be used? See below:

```
import pandas as pd

import numpy as np

#create dataframe with 5 columns using random numbers 

rng = np.random.RandomState(42)

df = pd.DataFrame(rng.rand(1000, 5), columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D','E'])

df2= round((df * 10),1)

%timeit df3 = df2[(df2["A"] < 3) & (df2["B"]>2)]

%timeit df4 = df2.query("A<3 and B>2")
```

for df3 I got: 1.06 ms ± 156 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

for df4: 1.97 ms ± 155 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

As you can see, df4 took almost twice as long. Why??? Are there limitations on using query(). I find query() syntax much cleaner and easier to use I was hoping to use it by default.

I am using Pandas 0.24.2

Comment: I would say that referencing a post from 2014 using version `0.13` (while pandas is currently in `0.24.`) probably has very little truth to it. Here's a more recent post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936557/pandas-dataframe-loc-vs-query-performance that indicates that query is generally slower.

Comment: There's likely to be a not entirely linear relationship between time, method and volume. Could be that for this particular size of dataframe, the ampersand method is faster for a 2-condition query. I'd expect differently complex queries, over differently sized and structured dataframes to have differing optimal curves across a range of volumes. There's likely to be a minor parsing overhead with the SQL method that should be a static cost that's irrespective of volume - maybe with so few rows, that cost isn't being recouped by the increase in processing speed? You need more tests.

Comment: Anecdotally, on 900M row dataset, .query ran around 20X quicker for me than using .loc[]

Answer (score 3):

There is some overheads when using `eval` and `query`. As indicated in the [userguide documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/enhancingperf.html#pandas-eval-performance) operations are faster using plain Python for smaller dataframe (around 20k rows). Here, your dataframe has only 1k rows.

For your specific example, on my machine with pandas 1.2.1, and python 3.8, I get faster results with `query` when the dataframe is about 10 millions rows.

However, I think that `query` vs other method to filter data is more of a syntax convenience than a performance enhancer (there is other tools for that, e.g.  Dask, Numba, Modin, Vaex, rapids, etc).

##### Screenshot of faster results with query with 10**7 rows.

[image]

##### Screenshot of the documentation