# How would I group, summarize and filter a DF in pandas in dplyr-fashion?

Tags: python, r, pandas, dplyr

I'm currently studying pandas and I come from an R/dplyr/tidyverse background.

Pandas has a not-so-intuitive API and how would I elegantly rewrite such operation from dplyr using pandas syntax?

```r
library("nycflights13")
library("tidyverse")

delays <- flights %>%
  group_by(dest) %>%
  summarize(
    count = n(),
    dist = mean(distance, na.rm = TRUE),
    delay = mean(arr_delay, na.rm = TRUE)
  ) %>%
  filter(count > 20, dest != "HNL")
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> pd.DataFrame.agg method doesn't allow much flexibility for changing columns' names in the method itself

That's not exactly true. You could actually rename the columns inside `agg` similar to in R although it is a better idea to not use `count` as a column name as it is also an attribute:

```
    delays = (
    flights
    .groupby('dest', as_index=False)
    .agg(
        count=('year', 'count'),
        dist=('distance', 'mean'),
        delay=('arr_delay', 'mean'))
    .query('count > 20 & dest != "HNL"')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

Comment: Wow, thank you very much. I was breaking my head, thinking there was no way to do this king of column-naming with `agg`

Answer (score 2):

We can write a pandas concatenation of functions and methods that results in the same dataframe/tibble:

```py
delays = (
    flights
    .groupby('dest', as_index=False)
    .agg({
        'year': 'count',
        'distance': 'mean',
        'arr_delay': 'mean',
    })
    .rename(columns={
        'year': 'count',
        'distance': 'dist',
        'arr_delay': 'delay',
    })
    .query('count > 20 & dest != "HNL"')
    .reset_index(drop=True)
)
```

It's more lengthy: Pandas' `pd.DataFrame.agg` method doesn't allow much flexibility for changing columns' names in the method itself.

But it's as elegant, clean and clear as pandas allows us to go.

Comment: Very nice. My only concern is related to `.query()` -- that it's much slower than the regular `df.loc[df.col.values > ..., ]` stuff

Comment: Thank you. About `.query()`, I was basing myself on [this chapter by Jake VanderPlas ](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/03.12-performance-eval-and-query.html) about High-Peformance Pandas. Do u have any text about `query()` 's performance?

Comment: I saw tests [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49936557/pandas-dataframe-loc-vs-query-performance) and then tested it myself with the same results. This is sad, because I like query's syntax and SQL-like outlook.